# Is there a way to embed a flipbook into a website using an iframe to display on desktop at one size and a different size on mobile?

Tags: html, iframe, embedding

I am adding a flipbook that I created on fliphtml5 to a website using an iframe. The flipbook looks great on a desktop but does not display correctly on mobile. On a mobile device, it only displays a portion of the flipbook.

Wondering if there is a code condition statement that can be added to the iframe, so the flipbook displays at one size for desktop, and if mobile, it hides desktop and displays at whatever size is appropriate for mobile.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the meta viewport tag in the head and media queries in css.
The meta viewport tag goes like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This is the most common viewport tag, although you can create one on your own.

The media screen queries are a part of css. They start as follows:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px /for  mobile phones*/) {
/*CSS for mobiles*/
}
```

Learn about media queries [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries)